# Java- how to ignore quotes inside quotes

Tags: java, json, regex

I have some unescaped quotes in the value part of my json file,

```
"key":"value"
```

it is like

```
"text":"a personal persona as a street-smart "tough girl", which when 
combined with raw talent","birthday":"19871108"
```

I am wondering how use regex to make the escape the quote inside my value part?
Make it looks like

```
"text":"a personal persona as a street-smart \"tough girl\", which when 
combined with raw talent","birthday":"19871108"
```

Comment: Use in regex `\\\"`

Comment: @SHG I think you mean `\"`. `\\\"` is registered as `\"`, and it provides unnecessary trouble.

Comment: I am not still not sure what to put in my regex, does \" just mean match " ?

Comment: @YIWENGONG What is the input string, and exactly is the substring that you want to match?

Comment: This is not possible to do reliably in the general case. I'd recommend looking into fixing the broken process that's creating this file.

Comment: @SHG Input string is a broken json file, it has unescaped quotes like the "tough girl", I want to escape these kinds of quotes

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder `\\\"` is better. It's true that they both have the same result. But - many times, when one wants to build/test his regex, he uses [regex10](https://regex101.com) and similar websites. And then, you'd want to copy your regex and the string to match against to this website. When your regex has only `\"` it won't match, but if it has `\\\"` it will!

Comment: @YIWENGONG I agree with @ruakh. It will not be possible/reliable, unless you have some assumptions about the content, for instance: that it doesn't contain the next key name (`birthday` in your case) AND that `birthday` will always be the next key after `text` (which I'm not sure can be guaranteed in JS).

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is not finding quotes using regular expression, but finding *unescaped* quotes using regular expression.

The definition of an unescaped quote is one that is preceded by an even number of backslashes (zero backslashes being the most common case).

The expression for that is this ugly thing:

```
(?<!(?:[^\\]|$)(?:\\{2})?\\)"
```

If you think that's bad, check out the escaped version in Java:

```
(?<!(?:[^\\\\]|$)(?:\\\\{2})?\\\\)\"
```

What this essentially does is find all quotes that haven't been escaped already.  The test string I used was: `Testing "unescaped".  \"escaped\".  \\"unescaped again\\"`  The regex matches only the first and third sets of quotation marks, not the escaped second set.

It should be replaced by `\"` or in java, `\\\"`.

Try it and let me know!